# How to convert the U+XXXXX sequence to character in perl?

Tags: perl

This

```
perl -CO -E 'say "\N{U+00E1}"'
```

prints

```
á
```

How to achieve to get the same á with the following:

```
echo "U+00E1" | perl -CO -lnE 'say what_here($_)'
```

Comment: With `-l`, you don't need `-E` and `say`.

Comment: Echo command can also generate UTF-8 : `echo -e '\UE1' | perl -CSA -nE 'print $_'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [charnames](http://p3rl.org/charnames):

```
echo "U+00E1" | perl -Mcharnames=short -CO -lnE 'say charnames::vianame($_)'
```

You can also use `eval`, if you can control what comes in as input:

```
echo "U+00E1" | perl -CO -lnE 'say eval qq("\\N{$_}")'
```

Comment: thanx. aceepting in 4 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

Pure basic Perl solution:

```
echo "U+00E1" | perl -C -nE 'say chr(hex) if s/U\+//'
```

Please, do not use unsafe (`eval`) solutions like:

```
echo "U+00E1" | perl -C -nE 's/U\+/0x/;eval qq{say chr($_)}'
```

Comment: like the `pack`, but honestly, still not understanding how the pack works.

Comment: @kobame: `pack` is nice, but returns something else than "á".

Comment: Yes, it was not visible what is wrong. It is fixed now.

Comment: I'm still getting a different output. Check with `xxd`.

Comment: `$ echo "U+00E1" | perl -C -nE 's/U\+/0x/;eval qq{say chr($_)}' | xxd
00000000: c3a1 0a                                  ...
$ echo "U+00E1" | perl -C -nE 'say chr(hex) if s/U\+//' | xxd
00000000: c3a1 0a                                  ...
$ echo "U+00E1" | perl -Mcharnames=short -CO -lnE 'say charnames::vianame($_)' | xxd
00000000: c3a1 0a`

Answer (score 1):

Using `pack`

```
echo U+0041 U+0042 U+0043 U+00E1 | perl -ne"print pack 'U', hex for /\p{hex}+/g"
```

#### output

```
ABCá
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "U+00E1" | perl -CO -lnE 'eval "\$a=\"\\N{$_}\";"; say $a;'
```

Comment: This answer would be better with some explanation of the code.